# Finding an appropriate preg_match regular expression

Tags: php, preg-match

I have got a little problem, while coding.  I have a text string like

```
"This is a {cat} with {big} eyes."
```

What I want to do is, I want an appropriate preg_match regular expression, so that I could extract the words written in curly braces from a sentence. I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: You must have given this a shot already. Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

That's rather simple...

```
preg_match_all("/\{[^}]+\}/", $str, $matches);
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/lIrtNl).

Examine the `$matches` array. If you don't want the braces as part of your match, you can use a capturing group (`"/\{([^}]+)\}/"`) or cut out the braces with alternative methods.

Answer (score 0):

How's this: `/\{(.*?)\}/`

That should work :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str="This is a {cat} with {big} eyes";
echo preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z\s]/", "",$str);
```